# How to hide specific columns of a datatable on mobile devices

Tags: datatable, responsive

I want a datatable to show the second column with first priority, the fifth column with second priority and the first column with third priority. To achieve that I integrated this CSS link:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">
```

and added this in the HTML part:

```
<th data-priority="1">
```

But the datatable does not hide any columns, not even the columns on the right side as I would expect by default settings.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/h7Lg6cqt/4/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have not added the script required for responsive column hiding. Add, `https://cdn.datatables.net/colreorder/1.5.2/js/dataTables.colReorder.min.js` and DataTable will auto hide columns when screen size is small.

Also add the responsive plugin script `https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js`

If you want to hide particular columns, then you need to add `display class` on the column. Check out `https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-control/classes.html` for more details. For your case, adding below code will hide 2 columns.

```
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th class="min-phone-l"></th>
      <th class="min-phone-l"></th>
      <th data-priority="1"></th>
    </tr>
```

For column reordering, check colReorder here : `https://datatables.net/extensions/colreorder/`

Comment: Hi shubham, thank you for your help! I added both pieces of code but I did not get the desired result: https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/h7Lg6cqt/9/ Do you know why?

Comment: Hi @JohannesChrist, you did not include the responsive js.  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>

Comment: Thank you, that was the hint I needed! It works fine now. https://jsfiddle.net/Joh_Christ/h7Lg6cqt/16/

Comment: Man I think I love you... I've been messing around with this for hours! Thank you!!